# "Reader and Data Access" role is not available through powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to assign "Reader and Data Access" role to my service principal in Azure however it's throwing an error

**I don't see this role listed on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) but visible on azure portal**

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment 
      -RoleDefinitionName 'Reader and Data Access' `
      -ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId`
```

> New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : The filter 'roleName eq 'Reader and Data
>   Access'' is not supported. Supported filters are either roleName eq
>   '{value}' or type eq 'BuiltInRole|CustomRole'

However I can see and assign this role from Azure UI console.

[image]

Comment: I don't have Azure but are you able to see the role when you try `Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment`

Comment: @Matt Yes I can see this role in powershell using `Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition` and I can also see the role has been listed being assigned using `Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment`

Comment: Is this a role that you were able to create or a predefined one? I ask because I wonder if there is a trailing space or hidden character in the name (not that it should be allowed).

Comment: Is't a predefined role. I never created any custom role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test in my lab, I get same error log with you. I solve this issue by using `-RoleDefinitionId` not `-RoleDefinitionName`. The following script works for me.

```
$value=Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition
$a=$value |where {$_.Name -eq "Reader and Data Access"}

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -Scope /subscriptions/$subscriptionID -RoleDefinitionId $a.Id
```

Comment: Is it going to grant permission to ServicePrincipal or Application?

Comment: They are all supported.